# Simple code to read local file from a selection from dropdown box and display it in a textarea (Javascript/ XHTML)

Tags: javascript, xhtml, textarea, dropdownbox

I've been trying for days to create a simple code to create a page that can display text files from a local directory. These are the specifications.

- XHTML/ Javascript only
- Files are local and from the same directory as the homepage
- Files are in txt/ log form
- Files to be displayed are to be selected from a dropdown box
- Files are to be displayed in a text area
- Compatible for all web browsers, can't use ActiveXObject

This was my closest attempt.

**JavaScript**

```
function populate(filename)
{
 var file = document.getElementById('log1').files.(0);
 var reader = new FileReader();
 reader.onload = function(e)
 {
  document.getElementById('myTextarea').value = e.target.result;
 };
 reader.readAsText(file);
}
```

**(X)HTML**

```
<div id="source1">
    <form id="log1">
        Select File from cng1wlsbe1b:<br />
        <select name="file1">
            <option value="CCS1be1" onclick="populate('log1','ACCS1be1.txt')">CCS1be1</option>
            <option value="CCS1beadm1" onclick="populate('log1','cng1wlsbe1bCCS1beadm1.txt')">CCS1beadm1</option>
            <option value="engine_A" onclick="populate('log1','cng1wlsbe1bengine_A.txt')">engine_A</option>
        </select>
    </form>
    <textarea rows="10" id="myTextarea" name="comment" form="log1" style="width:100%"></textarea>
</div>
```

I just learned coding and I've been taking in bits and pieces of codes from everywhere, so I'm quite sure it's littered with errors. Will any kind Samaritan please enlighten me?

Thank you!

- Robin :)

Comment: From MDN: "The FileReader object lets web applications asynchronously read the contents of files (or raw data buffers) stored on the user's computer, using File or Blob objects to specify the file or data to read."

So files can be read from the users computer, not from the webserver. See here for examples: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications

Answer (score 0):

I have enough time to at least get you on track with some very insightful things that will put gas in your tank and across the desert.

- Use XHTML5 (file names ending with `.xhtml` until you learn how to work with server code). HTML is parsed (looked at and done stuff with) by the HTML parser which is akin to the army recruiting 4channers only there will be no lulz. XHTML is rendered by the XML parser, it's strict and while not perfect it will (while using Firefox) tell you when you reload the page what the error is as well as what line and column it's located at *so you can fix the problem now* instead of lulz-wat-problem?
- In JavaScript when you have an array (more than one item being contained it will use solid brackets. In example `document.getElementById('example`)`is singular though if you want to use`document.getElementsByTagName('a`)[0]` it will use `[0]` for the first occurrence, `[1]` for second, `[2]` for third and so forth (without quotes).
- Use double quotes for (X)HTML `<element attribute="values" />` and single quotes for JavaScript syntax, it will save you a *lot* of hassle in the future. Also don't mind the whitespace, if you code well you'll use minimal spaces and only ever have more than one space in a row (or more) in JavaScript and your server (aka back-end) code. HTML is `text/html` whereas XHTML is *only* XHTML if it's served as `application/xhtml+xml`; what version the (X)HTML is has nothing to do with the media type/mime.
- When in doubt check **MDN** (Mozilla Developer Network). Just append `mdn` to your search queries. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FileReader
- *Never* use a framework if you want to be competent, most people can't do actual real code and the more dependencies you add the weaker your code becomes and the easier an update to something third party will break everything...on your wedding day.
- Use WinMerge to compare old code to new code, it's freeware and I've never stopped using it.
- Use your browser's developer tools (specifically the **console**) when trying to debug any JavaScript code. Keep in mind that not all errors will produce output, silent errors suck and hopefully you won't have to deal with silent errors for a good while.
- Save this code using **Notepad++** and ensure it's encode as UTF-8 **without a BOM (byte order mark)** which is only necessary for UTF-16 (you won't be using that unless you're exceptionally local to India I think it is). There is no perfect editor though for freeware once you get used to it you'll find it fairly capable and not sucking up 4GB of RAM, a very respectable balance.

I've cleaned up the code in general and made a basic application. I've never worked with local text files...I know that the user will have to initiate a request to the client (while testing your computer is *both* the client and the server). The user will *have* to use a file input element to select files *before anything can happen*.

This is a fairly advanced topic for you to take on initially though with enough tenacity you'll be able to conquer it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<title>Sample XHTML5 Application</title>
<script defer="defer" type="application/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
function populate(filename)
{
 var file = document.getElementById('log1').files[0];
 var reader = new FileReader();
 reader.onload = function(e)
 {
  document.getElementById('myTextarea').value = e.target.result;
 };
 reader.readAsText(file);
}
//]]>
</script>
<style type="text/css">

</style>
</head>

<body>

<form id="log1">
<fieldset>
<p>Select File from cng1wlsbe1b:</p>

<input onclick="populate(document.getElementById('file1').value);" type="button" value="clicky clicky" />
<input id="file_upload" type="file" value="" />

<select id="file1" name="file1">
<option value="CCS1be1" onclick="populate('log1','ACCS1be1.txt')">CCS1be1</option>
<option value="CCS1beadm1" onclick="populate('log1','cng1wlsbe1bCCS1beadm1.txt')">CCS1beadm1</option>
<option value="engine_A" onclick="populate('log1','cng1wlsbe1bengine_A.txt')">engine_A</option>
</select>

<textarea rows="10" id="myTextarea" name="comment" form="log1" style="width:100%"></textarea>
</fieldset>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

This won't directly answer your question though it will help you get a couple years past the challenges you'd face on your own and put you in striking distance of your goal. Good luck!